# Can I create a class method usable by each property of an created object?

Tags: javascript, object, methods

Can I create a method usable by each property of an object?

```
class myClass {
    constructor() {
        this.a = 1;
        this.b = 2;
        this.c = 3;
    }
    raise(x) {
        this += x;              //I know this doesn't work. I want the raise function to use 
                                //the value of its caller and increase it by x
    };
}
```

What I want to achieve is being able to call the raise method on any object property via

```
obj1 = new myClass();

obj1.a.raise(1);            //a = 2
obj1.b.raise(3);            //b = 5
obj1.c.raise(100);          //c = 103
```

So I want to be able to use this syntax: object.property.method()

I tried creating raise on the class constructor, the class prototype or the Object prototype. I also couldn't find any mention of this elsewhere.

Comment: You couldn't find any mention of it because it's not part of the language. You *can* pass the name of a property as a string and then use `[ ]` notation to access a property.

Comment: Nearly all the answers here require you to use a `get()` function to grab the value or do something like `.val`. For each of those cases, `m.a, m.b and m.c` are objects. There is one way, however, where you *will still* get an object but a JS Number object. See my answer.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. My aim was to be able to define 1 methods with a generic behavior (like increase the calling property by x) and have it work for all properties, similar to how the hasOwnProperty() method works on any object or property. So I could save the memory of having a get function for each property. The number object method would still create a method for each property or?

Answer (score -1):

It would be impossible for `obj.a` to return a number, while also being able to call `obj.a.raise` to modify it.

If you're open to a small tweak, you could retrieve the value via a method called something like `.get`, while the underlying value is stored and reassigned in the `_a` property:

```js
class myClass {
  constructor() {
    this._a = 1;
    this.a = { raise: num => this._a += num, get: () => this._a };
  }
}
const obj = new myClass();

obj.a.raise(1);            //a = 2
console.log(obj.a.get());
```

Comment: I am quite certain the author wanted to access the variable like `obj.a`, not `obj.a.get()`.

Comment: That's up to OP to say - but without something like `.get()`, one often won't be able to use the underlying number without taking it out of the object first

Comment: That depends on what kind of object. In a `Number` object, you don't have to pick the number out, you can do something like: `(new Number(1)) + 1` which will give you the primitive `2`.

Comment: Also, *"It would be impossible for obj.a to return a number, while also being able to call obj.a.raise to modify it."* is false. Again, a `Number` object returns a number, but you can also put a function in it.

Comment: You still have to cast somehow to get the underlying number out - you can't do a test like `this.a === 5`. What you have with `Number` is an object, not a number

Comment: Well you do have a point, but you can simply do: `this.a.valueOf() === 5` or `this.a == 5` if you want to compare. And while `Number` objects *are* objects, they are still *(in a way)* Numbers.

Answer (score -1):

Using ES6 you can do it easily. You may not need complex solution!
Sample is given below.

2nd Solution, to use composition.

```js
class PriceList {
  constructor(price, amount) {
    this._price = price;
    this._amount = amount;
  }

  get price() {
    return this._price;
  }

  set price(p) {
    this._price += p; // validation could be checked here such as only allowing non numerical values
  }
  get amount() {
    return this._amount;
  }

  set amount(p) {
    this._amount += p; // validation could be checked here such as only allowing non numerical values
  }
}
const priceList = new PriceList(1, 10);
console.log(priceList); // PriceList { _price: 1, _amount: 10 }
priceList.amount = 10;
priceList.price = 100;

console.log(priceList); // PriceList { _price: 101, _amount: 20 }
class Value {
  constructor(v) {
    this._val = v;
  }
  get val() {
    return this._val;
  }
  set(v) {
    this._val = v;
  }
  raise(m) {
    this._val += m;
  }
}
class PriceList2 {
  constructor(price, amount) {
    this.amount = new Value(amount);
    this.price = new Value(price);
  }
}
const priceList2 = new PriceList2(1, 10);
console.log(priceList2);
priceList2.amount.raise(10);
priceList2.price.raise(100);

console.log(priceList2.amount.val); // 20
console.log(priceList2.price.val); // 101

priceList2.amount.val = 1
priceList2.amount.raise(10);

console.log(priceList2.amount.val); //30
```

```css
.as-console-row {color: blue!important}
```

Comment: Are *three whole classes* required for this?? If they are, the solution is quite complex.

Comment: @LearnforFun: I have given way how can be done. anyone can simplify it. refactor it.

Answer (score -1):

For literally *all* answers (except this one), you need to run a function to get the value, here it's more simplified.

```js
class myClass {
    constructor() {
        this.a = new Number(1);
        this.b = new Number(2);
        this.c = new Number(3);
        
        for (let p in this) {
          this[p].raise = x => {
            let fn = this[p].raise;
            this[p] = new Number(x + this[p]);
            this[p].raise = fn;
          }
        }
    }
}
let m = new myClass();
m.a.raise(15);
m.a.raise(15);
// A = 1 + 15 + 15 = 31
m.b.raise(10);
m.b.raise(20);
// B = 2 + 10 + 20 = 32
m.c.raise(17);
m.c.raise(13);
// C = 3 + 17 + 13 = 33
console.log(m.a + 1, m.b + 1, m.c + 1) // 32  33  34
// logging just m.a, m.b, m.c will get you an object with a raise function
// only in stack overflow (or maybe other fake consoles), but the browser
// console will definitely work and give you a Number object
```